# How can share images on facebook from an iphone app using social framework in ios 6.0?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I used the code given below. But it only post image to facebook.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"testimage.png"];
    NSString *caption = @"Gud Mng";
    NSArray *activityItems = @[image, caption];
    // Initialize Activity View Controller
    UIActivityViewController *vc = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];
    // Present Activity View Controller
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: "but it only post image to facebook." - and isn't that what you want? Also, this is not an Xcode-related question.

Comment: @Nila,clearly mention your requirement in question, so that anyone can help you

Comment: @RamuPasupuleti: I've a 'share' button in my app when click on that button Image and some text will share to facebook.

Comment: @H2CO3: I just want to share an image, not post.

Answer (score 1):

Add social framework. Import in your view controller.

```
SLComposeViewController *socialVc=[SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.defaultImageView.image, 1.0);
[socialVc addImage:[UIImage imageWithData:data]];


[socialVc setInitialText:[NSString    stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.captionTextFeild.text]];
[socialVc addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"via www.coderit.com"]];
[self.navigationController presentViewController:socialVc animated:YES completion:nil];
```